# Navigation bar is not appearing properly (showing as floating instead of fix bar)

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, xcode11

With Navigation bar, why it shows a floating card view instead of the fix navigation bar
?[image]

What will be the configuration to show as a fixed navigation bar?

Comment: are you trying to present new viewcotroller. or push it?

Comment: I am pushing it using story board : show (e.g. push)

Comment: can you share what you have tried. like push view controller code.

Comment: I have set presentation as full screen in Interfacebuilder

Comment: I have observed that only initial viewcontroller is coming properly with out any space in navigation bar .... remaining all viewcontroller are showing some space in the top as it is showing in above image

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13 or higher, you have to set the UIViewController's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen` before presenting it.

For example:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You have to do this for every single ViewController you present.